# calling copy-constructor after simple inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor

I have a doubt regarding some concept of inheritance, i am stating what i know, please correct me if i am wrong.

Private members of base class are inherited by the derived class but derived class can't access them by any means.

Protected members of base class are inherited by the derived class but derived class can't access it directly, but by the help of some of its member functions.

Now in the following code:

```
class A
    {
        protected:
        A(const A&){}
        A operator=(const A &){}
        int t;
        public:
        A(int r)   {t=r;}
        A(){t=0;}
     };

class B : public A
      {
       A a;
      public:
      void make(void)
      {
         //A b(a);      //LINE 1 -------COPY CONSTRUCTOR BEING CALLED ---protected member of base class 
         cout<<t;   //LINE 2 -------protected member of base class 
      }
      };

   int main()
   {
        B b;
        b.make();
        return 0;
   }
```

Why there is error for LINE 1 coming??

Why we can't call copy-constructor for object of A?

Many many thanx in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A protected member can only be accessed by other members of the same complete object, during construction, destruction, or via the `this` pointer<sup>(*)</sup>.

In your example class hierarchy, a `B` object has two subobjects of type `A`:

- The base class subobject, which it gets by deriving from `A`, and
- The data member subobject named `a`, which it gets by declaring `a`.

A member of `B` may only access protected members from the first `A` subobject, not from the second, because only the first directly uses the `this` pointer (note that your expression `cout << t` is semantically equivalent to `cout << this->t`).

Access to the members of the data member do not directly use the `this` pointer:  if you tried to access `this->a.t` from `B::make`, the `this` pointer is not used directly to access the `t`.  In your declaration `A b(a);`, the copy constructor is called not for `this`, but for the new `A` object you are constructing, the local variable named `b`.

---

<sup>(*) Or, of course, by any member in the class that declares it:  any member function of `B` can call any other member function of `B`</sup>

Comment: It means that we can't create base class object from derived class if they are protected?

Comment: Constructor also uses this pointer, it means there is no way to create an object by the derived class of the base class, if all the base class constructors are protected

Comment: @Luv:  If all of the constructors of a class are protected, then that class may only be constructed as a base class of some other class type.  A derived class may call protected constructors for its base class subobjects.